# Python: Itertools groupby for unique key value pairs

Tags: python, csv, group-by, python-itertools

I'm trying to group data in a csv file based on a column. I tried:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv
with open('path/trial.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    things = list(reader)

for key, group in groupby(things, lambda x: x[0]):
    listOfThings = len(",".join([thing[1] for thing in group]).split(","))
    print key + "," + str(listOfThings)
```

It worked when data in column 1 is in a certain order. If it repeats, the counts are getting messed up.

With

```
A,1
A,2
A,1
B,0
B,8
```

I get

```
A,3
B,2
```

With

```
A,1
A,2
B,0
B,8
A,1
```

I get

```
A,2
B,2
A,1
```

I'd like my script to consider both unique keys and unique values and the output to be (taking A,1 only once, though it is present twice):

```
A,2
B,2
```

Based on Chad Simmon's comment, changed it to:

```
sortedlist = list(reader)
things= sorted(sortedlist, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

It now gives me

```
B,2
A,3
```

I want A,2 instead.

Comment: ```groupby``` only groups consecutive repeats. If you want to group the entire collection you need to use a dictionary or similar.

Comment: @ChadSimmons Thanks for the comment. Tried sorting and part of it worked. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by doing:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv, operator, itertools
with open('trial.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sortedlist = list(reader)
    things= sorted(sortedlist, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
    things.sort()
    things = list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(things))

for key, group in groupby(things, lambda x: x[0]):
    listOfThings = len(",".join([thing[1] for thing in group if not thing in things[1]]).split(","))
    print key + "," + str(listOfThings)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what Chad Simmons meant was that you should use something other than `groupby()` if you want to determine uniqueness in the context of the entire collection. However, instead of using a dictionary, I would suggest instead that you use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#set-types-set-frozenset) — which is similar to one — in addition to a subclass of dictionaries called a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

First construct a `set` of all the unique pairs of values in the file, and then construct a `Counter` of those which only considers the first value of the pair (what you called their *key*). If you want the results ordered, you'll also need to sort the contents of the `Counter` since it's unordered as it is in a dictionary, as is also demonstrated below.

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

with open('trial.csv', 'rb') as f:
    unique_pairs = set((row[0], row[1]) for row in csv.reader(f))
    for key, count in sorted(Counter(pair[0] for pair in unique_pairs).items()):
        print('{},{}'.format(key, count))
```